# How do I correctly create the container that FlutterFire is expecting for phone auth on web?

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm working off of [this documentation of FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone#web-signinwithphonenumber)

I'm trying to implement phone sign-in on web. The guide seems to recommend that RecaptchaVerifier is an optional argument:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance

// Wait for the user to complete the reCAPTCHA & for a SMS code to be sent.
ConfirmationResult confirmationResult = await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber('+44 7123 123 456');
```

However, when I try to use the method I am forced to supply an argument for RecaptchaVerifier:

[image]

I have verified I'm using the correct version of the library -- `firebase_auth: "^0.18.0+1"`.

So, in order to correctly display the Recaptcha verifier, how do I create an element on the DOM with the ID specified?

I found the [following relevant code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/4a05ceba74c805bc5528137d40c75865cd21d687/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_web/lib/firebase_auth_web_recaptcha_verifier_factory.dart) in their Github which shows how the element is accessed, however specific understanding of the source code eludes me.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes so I have been through this exact same issue. the problem here is that the documentation is not sync with PR : The PR that changes the doc has been merged ***but*** the plugin firebase_auth you're using hasn't been changed yet so you still have the old plugin , and the new doc..
So the solution is :

You have to take a precise commit of the plugin like this below dependencies in your pubspec :

```
firebase_auth: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire
      path: packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth
      ref: 4a05ceba74c805bc5528137d40c75865cd21d687
```

And also below dependencies_override, like this (add it if not there, below the dev_dependencies section) :

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_auth_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire
      path: packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_web
      ref: 4a05ceba74c805bc5528137d40c75865cd21d687
  firebase_auth_platform_interface:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire
      path: packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_platform_interface
      ref: 4a05ceba74c805bc5528137d40c75865cd21d687
```

Btw the reason you need override on dependencies is because the firebase_auth plugin, with the precise commit still uses old versions of the flutter web plugin

Comment: Awesome thanks for the detailed answer. I hope this is rectified soon by the maintainers.

Comment: So do we remove the recaptcha argument or do we leave one in?